# How to append grails logging using profiler into custom appender(log file)?

Tags: grails, profiler

Using grails profiler plugin, I want to append logging into separate file only for profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create an appender and then set the appropriate logger (looks to be com.linkedin.grails) to append to it with additivity set to false.

grails 3.x:

```
appender("PROFILER", FileAppender) {
    file = "profiler.log"
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
   }
}

logger("com.linkedin.grails", DEBUG, ["PROFILER"], false) // false here is for additivity
```

grails before 3:

```
file name: 'profiler', file: 'profiler.log', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS]} [%t] %-5p: %c %x - %m%n')

debug profiler: [
            "com.linkedin.grails"
], additivity: false
```